# Scraping USA Today Using the Wayback Machine

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the news title and its url from the USA today website on:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220101001435/https://www.usatoday.com/

Excerpt of the soup it returned that i need:

```
<a class="section-helper-flex section-helper-row ten-column spacer-small p1-container" data-index="2" data-module-name="promo-story-thumb-small" href="https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nfl/2021/12/31/nfl-predictions-wrong-worst-preseason-mvp-super-bowl/9061437002/" onclick="firePromoAnalytics(event)"><div class="section-helper-flex section-helper-column p1-text-wrap"><div class="promo-premium-content-label-wrap"></div><div class="p1-title"><div class="p1-title-spacer">Revisiting our worst NFL predictions of 2021: What went wrong?</div></div><div class="p1-info-wrap"><span class="p1-label">NFL</span>
```

I don't know how to take specific excerpts like this out of the whole soup as it should with as i assume:

```
links=soup.find_all('a',href=True)
```

code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests

url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20220101001435/https://www.usatoday.com/'
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

links=soup.find_all('a',href=True)
print (links)
```

I expect an output of a 2-D array with the first element being the title and the second element being the link, something like:

```
[...[Revisiting our worst NFL predictions of 2021: What went wrong?,https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nfl/2021/12/31/nfl-predictions-wrong-worst-preseason-mvp-super-bowl/9061437002/],...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exactly what you want:

```py
titles = [title.text for title in soup.select("div.p1_title > div.p1-title-spacer")]
urls = [link["href"] for link in soup.select("a.section-helper-flex.section-helper-row.ten-column.spacer-small.p1-container")]
output = list(zip(titles, urls))
print(output)
```

What you were doing wrong is that soup.findall returns a list of `bs4.element.Tag`s, not lists containing the text and href.

I used a list comprehension which sought out all `div`s of the class `p1-title-spacer` which were children of a `div` with class `p1_title` and extracted the text from each of them. Similarly, I used CSS selectors to extract the urls too.

I recommend that you read the [documentation for findall](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all).

Alternatively, you could do this without using beautifulsoup at all, purely using selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

titles = [title.text for title in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ""div.p1_title > div.p1-title-spacer"")]
urls = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.section-helper-flex.section-helper-row.ten-column.spacer-small.p1-container")]
output = list(zip(titles, urls))
print(output)
```

You could also look into [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to ensure that you don't look for elements before they've loaded.

Here's the whole thing:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests

url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20220101001435/https://www.usatoday.com/'
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
titles = [title.text for title in soup.select("div.p1_title > div.p1-title-spacer")]
urls = [link["href"] for link in soup.select("a.section-helper-flex.section-helper-row.ten-column.spacer-small.p1-container")]
output = list(zip(titles, urls))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all` returns a list of `bs4.element.Tag`, not a list of title and href. The `href=True` specified merely makes sure that the `a` elements selected have the attribute `href` with them.

So here is the complete code that will do what you want:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# 1.
url = "https://web.archive.org/web/20220101001435/https://www.usatoday.com/"
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# 2.
links = soup.find_all("a", class_="section-helper-flex", href=True)

results = []
for link in links:
    # 3.
    title = link.find("div", class_="p1-title-spacer")
    href = link["href"]
    results.append([title.text, href])

print(results)
```

The process is as follows:

1. Get the HTML source, which you don't need `selenium` but can use the `requests` library. After that, parse that with `bs4`.
2. Find all the `<a>` elements. Since your original filter is way to generous that would get every single link on the page, I modified it so it will only yield elements that have articles.
3. Finally, extract the title inside `a` and the URL.